# Notepad++ Run Shortcut won't run with Python

Tags: shortcuts, python, notepad++

I am trying to run a code through Notepad++ to Python using

(attempt 1) Run, Run,C:\Python26\python.exe, Run

(attempt 2) Run, Run, C:\Python26\python26.exe $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH), Run

(attempt 1) opens the Python Command Window but it's blank and is not running the program I wrote in.

(attempt 2) doesn't do anything

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Add the location of the Python binary to your **PATH** environment variable, then you can call it with just the script name.

My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> PATH -> Edit

append a semicolon to the line along with your python binary location, eg:

```
C:\Perl\bin;C:\Python31\bin
```

Then you can use this in Notepad++:

```
cmd /K "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

this will allow you to run your program and keep the window open afterward so you can analyze it's output.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding what you mean. How about this? I have made it run with C:\Python26\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"...I forgot the ""...but it opens and closes in a flash. I think the /k is what I need but I don't know where to put it.

Comment: If you add **C:\Python26** to your path you don't need it, but you can use **cmd /k C:\Python26\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"**

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to hotkey shortcuts->run commands:

1. open containing folder
2. open current dir cmd

The 2nd will open a cmd.exe prompt, and cd to script's location.